# pandas groupby consecutive dates and multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this table wherein I would like to merge two rows together where 
`end_date[-1]= start_date[0] AND trained[-1] = trained[0]`

Optional: I also would like to retain the values of re, id, and name where diff is max.

```
use trained start       end          diff   re  id  name
a   FALSE   01/12/2010  03/01/2018   2,590  0   4   25
a   TRUE    03/01/2018  08/02/2019   401    0   4   25
a   TRUE    08/02/2019  09/02/2019   1      0   4   25
a   TRUE    09/02/2019  31/12/2019   325    1   4   25
b   FALSE   01/08/2016  15/05/2018   652    0   5   8
c   FALSE   01/07/2019  06/08/2019   36     0   4   4
c   TRUE    06/08/2019  18/05/2020   286    0   4   4
c   TRUE    18/05/2020  19/05/2020   1      0   4   4
c   TRUE    19/05/2020  01/09/2020   105    0   4   4
c   TRUE    01/09/2020  31/12/2019   (245)  1   4   15
```

goal:

```
use trained start       end          diff   re  id  name
a   FALSE   01/12/2010  03/01/2018   2,590  0   4   25
a   TRUE    03/01/2018  31/12/2019   727    0   4   25
b   FALSE   01/08/2016  15/05/2018   652    0   5   8
c   FALSE   01/07/2019  06/08/2019   36     0   4   4
c   TRUE    06/08/2019  31/12/2019   147    0   4   4
```

Comment: What is the reason you need the first row for 'start' and the last row for 'end'? Any values in the rest of the dataset that could determine why these rows are important ?

Answer (score 1):

With your logic, we can use `cumsum()` on the negated condition to identify the blocks. Then we can use `groupby`:

```
blocks = (df['trained'].ne(df['trained'].shift())
          |df['start'].ne(df['end'].shift())
         ).cumsum()
df.groupby([blocks,'use']).agg({   # change the functions to fit your need
    'trained':'first',
    'start':'first',
    'end':'last',
    'diff':'sum',
    're':'min',
    'id':'first',
    'name':'first'
}).reset_index('use')
```

---

```
  use  trained       start         end          diff  re  id  name
1   a    False  01/12/2010  03/01/2018         2,590   0   4    25
2   a     True  03/01/2018  31/12/2019       4011325   0   4    25
3   b    False  01/08/2016  15/05/2018           652   0   5     8
4   c    False  01/07/2019  06/08/2019            36   0   4     4
5   c     True  06/08/2019  31/12/2019  2861105(245)   0   4     4
```

Comment: this is partially correct, the only thing missing is the conditional groupby -- i.e. we're taking the values of re, id, and name WHEN diff is max

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want the `first` value for 'start' and `last` value from 'end' in your groupby:

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['use', 'trained'], as_index=False).agg({
    'start': 'first', 
    'end': 'last'})
```

You can use `groupby` again to get the index of the max values of 'diff' for each set of 'use' and 'trained'.

```
max_idx_values = df.groupby(['use', 'trained'])['diff'].idxmax().values
```

Now you can get the values for fields 're',  'id',  'name':

```
re_id_name_df = df.loc[df.index.isin(max_idx_values), 
                       ['use', 'trained', 're',  'id',  'name']]
```

Finally, you can merge the two results together to have everything in one dataframe:

```
final = grouped.merge(re_id_name_df, on=['use', 'trained'])
```

Here is all the code in one block:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['use', 'trained'], as_index=False).agg({
    'start': 'first', 
    'end': 'last'})
max_idx_values = df.groupby(['use', 'trained'])['diff'].idxmax().values
re_id_name_df = df.loc[df.index.isin(max_idx_values), 
                       ['use', 'trained', 're',  'id',  'name']]
final = grouped.merge(re_id_name_df, on=['use', 'trained'])
print(final)

  use  trained      start        end  re  id  name
0   a    False 2010-01-12 2018-03-01   0   4    25
1   a     True 2018-03-01 2019-12-31   0   4    25
2   b    False 2016-01-08 2018-05-15   0   5     8
3   c    False 2019-01-07 2019-06-08   0   4     4
4   c     True 2019-06-08 2019-12-31   0   4     4
```